BarChart without spacing in SwiftChart
I've tried to create Chart with bars without any spacing, I want it to look like AreaChart.
I have different array size, width and zoom. I calculate width of bars in this code below:
GeometryReader { geometry in
      ...                          
      let width = geometry.size.width / chartDataCount * viewModel.options.zoomValue                               
      chartContent(width: width)
      ...
}

And then:
private func chartContent(width: CGFloat) -> some View {
   Chart {
            ForEach(viewModel.spectrumChart.data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let point = viewModel.spectrumChart.data[index]
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("xValue", index),
                    yStart: .value("minValue", 0),
                    yEnd: .value("yValue", point.yValue),
                    width: .fixed(width)
                )
      ...
     }
      .chartXScale(domain: 0... viewModel.spectrumChart.data.count - 1)

}

What I've got
And what I need
How can I achieve the expected result?

Bar charts are usually used to display categorical data, where one of axes represents some kind of "category", instead of numbers. If you change your x axis to a String, it will become categorical data, and you can use width: .ratio(1) to say that each bar should occupy all the available width.
BarMark(
    x: .value("xValue", "\(index)"), // note that this is a string
    y: .value("yValue". point.yValue),
    width: .ratio(1)
)

Here is a more complete example:
struct ContentView: View {
        Chart([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], id: \.self) { i in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("X", "\(i)"),
                y: .value("Y", i),
                width: .ratio(1)
            )
        }
    }
}


It works very slow when data is huge or when its width dynamically changed

@MatveiKozin Why would you want to display huge amounts of data with a bar chart? And how huge are we talking about here? At 100 bars, my eyes can no longer see the individual bars. What nature is the data that you are presenting here? Perhaps an AreaMark would be a better choice?

Unfortunately, the AreaMark is not fit. I want to create this Charts https://ibb.co/2WRmHQ4

@MatveiKozin Why do you think it "is not fit"? You can do .interpolationMethod(.stepEnd) to make them look like bars, but with such thin bars, I doubt that would make much of a difference.

It draws the Chart incorrectly.
https://ibb.co/27WCM7v

@MatveiKozin You'd have to show a [mcve] for that, in a separate question. This question has just turned out to be an XY Problem.
